# Props in component are undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have parent  component

```
export default class Cities extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      answer: "",
      input: "",
    };
    this.answerChange = this.answerChange.bind(this);
    this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
  }

  answerChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      answer: e,
    });
  };
  inputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      input: e,
    });
  };
  
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.answer);
    console.log("this.state");

    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#F3F3F6" }}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Города</Text>
        <ScoreArea props={this.state} />
        <CitiesArea props={this.state} inputChange={this.inputChange} answerChange={this.answerChange} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and child component

```
export default class CitiesArea extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  backend = (text, answer)=>{
    /*request*/
    });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    console.log(this.props.answer)
    console.log(this.props.input)
    return (
      <View style={styles.form}>
        <Text style={styles.form__text}>Ответ:</Text>
        <View style={styles.input}>
          <Text style={styles.answer}>
            {this.props.answer}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.form__text}>Ваш вариант:</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder='Пишите здесь'
          onChangeText={text=>{this.props.inputChange(text)}}
        />
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Icon.Button style={styles.icon} backgroundColor={"#2e167d"} name="arrow-right" size={39} color={"#F3F3F6"}
                       onPress={()=> {
                         this.backend(this.props.input, this.props.answerChange)
                       }}>
          </Icon.Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

In the console i get the output:

{"answerChange": [Function bound ], "inputChange": [Function bound ], "props": {"answer": "", "input": ""}}

undefined

undefined

The functions that I pass work and the props changes, but when accessing the props value, i get undefined.
Moreover, if you refer to the value in the parent, then everything works

Comment: Replace `props={this.state}` with `{...this.state}`

Comment: The child component gets its properties, `this.props`, as you would expect. But you've named a property `props`, which would be accessed as `this.props.props`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the PARENT **states** to CHILD as **props**. you need to use ***spread operator*** like {...this.state}

```
<ScoreArea {...this.state} />
<CitiesArea {...this.state} inputChange={this.inputChange} answerChange={this.answerChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(this.props)` =>
`{"answerChange": [Function bound ], "inputChange": [Function bound ], "props": {"answer": "", "input": ""}}`

`console.log(this.props.answer)` => `undefined`

`console.log(this.props.input)` => `undefined`

You can access by `this.props.props.answer` in the child component.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the **this.props.props.answer** on CitiesArea component.
Because you send the value name with "props", so in your child component, It know value name is "props". so you should the call with "this.props.props.answer".

Please check with console.log(this.props.props.answer) on child component.